# Rails deep nesting with index of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following routes

```
  resources :continent do
    resources :countries do
        resource :cities do
            resource :streets
        end
    end
  end
```

To select a country I would have to do

```
/continents/:continent_id/countries/:country_id
```

and so on.

My question is how can I get all streets for a specific country or continent. Or all countries for a specific continent.

for example is there a way to do

```
/continents/:continent_id/countries/cities
```

which will return all cities under :continent_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep. Refer to: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

If you really need that deepness then you can solve that with shallow attribute set to true.
Refer to: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

**Update for better explain the use of shallow nesting**

```
rails new shallow-routes
cd shallow-routes
```

edit `config/routes.rb` to add your desired routes

```
  resources :continent do
    resources :countries do
        resource :cities do
            resource :streets
        end
    end
  end
```

now running `rake routes` we have this:

```
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                  Controller#Action
     continent_country_cities_streets POST   /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#create
 new_continent_country_cities_streets GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/streets/new(.:format)  streets#new
edit_continent_country_cities_streets GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/streets/edit(.:format) streets#edit
                                      GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#show
                                      PATCH  /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#update
                                      PUT    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#update
                                      DELETE /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#destroy
             continent_country_cities POST   /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#create
         new_continent_country_cities GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/new(.:format)          cities#new
        edit_continent_country_cities GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities/edit(.:format)         cities#edit
                                      GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#show
                                      PATCH  /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#update
                                      PUT    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#update
                                      DELETE /continent/:continent_id/countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#destroy
                  continent_countries GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries(.:format)                                 countries#index
                                      POST   /continent/:continent_id/countries(.:format)                                 countries#create
                new_continent_country GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/new(.:format)                             countries#new
               edit_continent_country GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:id/edit(.:format)                        countries#edit
                    continent_country GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#show
                                      PATCH  /continent/:continent_id/countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#update
                                      PUT    /continent/:continent_id/countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#update
                                      DELETE /continent/:continent_id/countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#destroy
                      continent_index GET    /continent(.:format)                                                         continent#index
                                      POST   /continent(.:format)                                                         continent#create
                        new_continent GET    /continent/new(.:format)                                                     continent#new
                       edit_continent GET    /continent/:id/edit(.:format)                                                continent#edit
                            continent GET    /continent/:id(.:format)                                                     continent#show
                                      PATCH  /continent/:id(.:format)                                                     continent#update
                                      PUT    /continent/:id(.:format)                                                     continent#update
                                      DELETE /continent/:id(.:format)                                                     continent#destroy
```

Let's change that resources for shallow nesting and look at the result

```
  resources :continent, shallow: true do
    resources :countries do
        resource :cities do
            resource :streets
        end
    end
  end
```

It's result

```
                     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                          Controller#Action
     country_cities_streets POST   /countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#create
 new_country_cities_streets GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/streets/new(.:format)  streets#new
edit_country_cities_streets GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/streets/edit(.:format) streets#edit
                            GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#show
                            PATCH  /countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#update
                            PUT    /countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#update
                            DELETE /countries/:country_id/cities/streets(.:format)      streets#destroy
             country_cities POST   /countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#create
         new_country_cities GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/new(.:format)          cities#new
        edit_country_cities GET    /countries/:country_id/cities/edit(.:format)         cities#edit
                            GET    /countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#show
                            PATCH  /countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#update
                            PUT    /countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#update
                            DELETE /countries/:country_id/cities(.:format)              cities#destroy
        continent_countries GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries(.:format)         countries#index
                            POST   /continent/:continent_id/countries(.:format)         countries#create
      new_continent_country GET    /continent/:continent_id/countries/new(.:format)     countries#new
               edit_country GET    /countries/:id/edit(.:format)                        countries#edit
                    country GET    /countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#show
                            PATCH  /countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#update
                            PUT    /countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#update
                            DELETE /countries/:id(.:format)                             countries#destroy
            continent_index GET    /continent(.:format)                                 continent#index
                            POST   /continent(.:format)                                 continent#create
              new_continent GET    /continent/new(.:format)                             continent#new
             edit_continent GET    /continent/:id/edit(.:format)                        continent#edit
                  continent GET    /continent/:id(.:format)                             continent#show
                            PATCH  /continent/:id(.:format)                             continent#update
                            PUT    /continent/:id(.:format)                             continent#update
                            DELETE /continent/:id(.:format)                             continent#destroy
```

an image of it's difference for better view https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8ylz.png

what we have here is that now the routes are simpler, a route like `/continent/:continent_id/countries` now exists only for **index, create and new** the others are outside of continent scope **in routes**

Notice that it is really helpful, because you don't need routes to tell you that an street is inside a continent, it's obvious, if your street is inside a city, it's of course inside a country and continent as well.

**Direct Answer - Now let's take a look at your goal here**

> /continents/:continent_id/countries/cities

You want all cities of the continent, why [the hell, sorry for it] do you need countries between them ?

I would just do `/continents/:id/cities`, much simpler and easy to understand.

To achieve that you just create a new route inside your continents resource

```
  resources :continent, shallow: true do
    member do
        get 'cities'
    end

    resources :countries do
        resource :cities do
            resource :streets
        end
    end
  end
```

and then you have this new nice route

```
cities_continent GET    /continent/:id/cities(.:format)                      continent#cities
```

Comment: for shallow-nesting how would I do my intended functionality

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation @Ramon Marques

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following model relation

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :streets, :through => : cities
end
```

So, you can use for example in the code

```
Country.find(1).streets
```